# Fill column based on the values of another one in a dynamic range and merge lines at the end for the cells within the same cable tag

Tags: excel, vba, range, fill

I'm trying to fill a column with color abreviations based on number of times a text appears on another column.
In the next image you can see that I have in the column C, starting at line 5 a cable tag, in this case this cable tag appears 2 times, so i need to fill the column E (lines 5 and 6) with 2 colors abreviations that are present in column J.
In this first case the column E line 5 will be equal to 1/BL and the line 6 will equal to 1/RD.
After this I need to go to the next cell that have another cable tag, in this case line 21, count how many times the cable tag appears and then fill the column E with the color abreviation, allways starting from the beginning of the colors abreviations.
After this go to the next cable tag and so on....

[image: Excel Terminals]

The values on column C are populated by excel formulas, the range and number of cable tags  will be different every time.
Next image shows another example

[image]

In this case the cable tag E/H72011 appears 10 times, so i need to fill the column E lines 19 to 28 with the colors abreviations, starting with 1/BL to 2/RD

After this I need to copy this entire sheet to a new one to remove the formulas and leave only the values and then merge the cells with the same value.
The end result is shown on the next image

[image]

Is it possible to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comments. I don't have much experience in VBA, and I'm not looking for a copy paste solution.
I started doing this yesterday and just listed the steps I think I should follow.
But I have no ideia how to start.

Comment: 1. Find the first row that contains the first cable ID (don't know how to avoid the header)
2. Pick the value from this first row and do a count to know how many times this value appears in the following rows
3. With this value do a loop through the column J/E to fill the column E with the color's abbreviations
4. Go to the next cable cable ID (No idea how to do this)
5. Repeat the point 3
6. Repeat the point 6
7. Copy and merge (No idea)